# How to add data into the column with null values from another table?

Tags: sql-server

I'm trying to populate my table with data gathered.

I have three table, INCIDENT_MAIN, INCIDENT_REPORT and PROJECT_PROFILE.

I have to fill the PROJECT_PROFILE table from the data provided by INCIDENT_MAIN AND INCIDENT_REPORT.

here is my query for doing INNER JOIN

```
INSERT INTO PROJECT_PROFILE (INCIDENT_REPORT_ID, PROJECT_NAME,PROJECT_TYPE, PROJECT_PHASE, PROJECT_START_DATE,PROJECT_END_DATE,DOMESTIC_INTERNATIONAL,PROJECT_FACILITIES_LOGISTIC)
  SELECT PROJECT_NAME, PROJECT_TYPE, PROJECT_PHASE, PROJECT_START_DATE, ESTIMATED_PROJECT_END_DATE, DOMESTIC_INTERNATIONAL, PROJECT_FACILITIES_LOGISTIC
  FROM INCIDENT_MAIN INCIDENT_REPORT_ID
  INNER JOIN INCIDENT_REPORT ON INCIDENT_REPORT.INCIDENT_REPORT_ID = PROJECT_PROFILE.INCIDENT_REPORT_ID
```

I got the error message of multi-part identifier 'PROJECT_PROFILE.INCIDENT_REPORT_ID'could not be bound

So I decide to populate the PROJECT_PROFILE table with INCIDENT_REPORT_ID first so that I can collect data which is INCIDENT_REPORT_ID from the INCIDENT_REPORT table. The PROJECT_PROFILE_ID is auto increment since I set it as IDENTITY KEY.

The data is inserted just fine. Below is the result.

[image]

234 rows affected.

Now, I try to replace the NULL values with the data from INCIDENT_MAIN

Here is the query

```
INSERT INTO PROJECT_PROFILE (PROJECT_NAME,PROJECT_TYPE, PROJECT_PHASE, PROJECT_START_DATE,PROJECT_END_DATE,DOMESTIC_INTERNATIONAL,PROJECT_FACILITIES_LOGISTIC)
  SELECT PROJECT_NAME, PROJECT_TYPE, PROJECT_PHASE, PROJECT_START_DATE, ESTIMATED_PROJECT_END_DATE, DOMESTIC_INTERNATIONAL, PROJECT_FACILITIES_LOGISTIC
  FROM INCIDENT_MAIN
  WHERE PROJECT_PROFILE_ID >='1'
```

But now, the data form INCIDENT_MAIN is inserted under the last row of 234 which makes the PROJECT_PROFILE_ID increased and the NULL VALUES ARE NOT REPLACED.

[image]

What is the right way to do the query so that the NULL values can be replaced with real data and there's no increment in PROJECT_PROFILE_ID.

**EDITED**

So, I tried this update query as per suggestion

```html
UPDATE PROJECT_PROFILE
SET PROJECT_PROFILE.PROJECT_NAME = INCIDENT_MAIN.PROJECT_NAME,
PROJECT_PROFILE.PROJECT_PHASE = INCIDENT_MAIN.PROJECT_PHASE,
PROJECT_PROFILE.PROJECT_START_DATE = INCIDENT_MAIN.PROJECT_START_DATE,
PROJECT_PROFILE.PROJECT_END_DATE = INCIDENT_MAIN.ESTIMATED_PROJECT_END_DATE,
PROJECT_PROFILE.DOMESTIC_INTERNATIONAL = INCIDENT_MAIN.DOMESTIC_INTERNATIONAL,
PROJECT_PROFILE.PROJECT_FACILITY_LOGISTIC = INCIDENT_MAIN.PROJECT_FACILITIES_LOGISTIC
FROM PROJECT_PROFILE JOIN INCIDENT_MAIN ON
PROJECT_PROFILE.PROJECT_NAME= INCIDENT_MAIN.PROJECT_NAME
WHERE PROJECT_PROFILE.PROJECT_PROFILE_ID <='234'
```

getting (0 rows affected)

Comment: before you execute the last query, there are data already in the table from earlier `INSERT` statement. If these are not what you wanted, delete it and re-execute the correct `INSERT` statement

Comment: The error in your first query on `PROJECT_PROFILE.INCIDENT_REPORT_ID` is because the query specified `PROJECT_PROFILE` but this table name or alias is not found in your query `FROM` clause at all

Comment: @Squirrel It is not what I want, I want to replace the null values with the real data from another table, but haven't found the right way to do it hence the question. Sorry if it's hard to understand.

Comment: You can use a `UPDATE` query  `FROM PROJECT_PROFILE JOIN INCIDENT_MAIN`

Comment: @Squirrel   tried the update query (0 rows affected)

Comment: please update your question with the update query

Comment: you are getting `0 rows affected` because, the `PROJECT_NAME` existing in the `PROJECT_PROFILE` table are all NULL. You will not be able to match it with `PROJECT_NAME` from `INCIDENT_MAIN`.

Comment: @Squirrel how to do this then?

Comment: are you able to delete `PROJECT_PROFILE` and re-do ? Get the query right with the first insertion. Then you don't need to handle the update part

Comment: @Squirrel Yes, I can do that

Comment: re-do is the best option. It might not be possible to fix the data

Comment: @Squirrel sure. But then how can I fix my inner join query? I'm no expert to be honest. Failed to do so for so many time already

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Without knowing your table schema, I am just guessing ...

I have changed the `JOIN` condition to `INCIDENT_REPORT.INCIDENT_REPORT_ID = INCIDENT_MAIN.INCIDENT_REPORT_ID`. If the column name is wrong, please amend accordingly

```
INSERT INTO PROJECT_PROFILE 
            (
                -- INCIDENT_REPORT_ID,  remove this line
                PROJECT_NAME,
                PROJECT_TYPE, 
                PROJECT_PHASE, 
                PROJECT_START_DATE,
                PROJECT_END_DATE,
                DOMESTIC_INTERNATIONAL,
                PROJECT_FACILITIES_LOGISTIC
            )
SELECT     PROJECT_NAME, 
           PROJECT_TYPE, 
           PROJECT_PHASE,  
           PROJECT_START_DATE, 
           ESTIMATED_PROJECT_END_DATE, 
           DOMESTIC_INTERNATIONAL, 
           PROJECT_FACILITIES_LOGISTIC
FROM       INCIDENT_MAIN INCIDENT_REPORT_ID
INNER JOIN INCIDENT_REPORT 
        ON INCIDENT_REPORT.INCIDENT_REPORT_ID = INCIDENT_MAIN.INCIDENT_REPORT_ID
```

My advice is, don't insert into the table. First you execute the query, staring from the `SEELCT` to the end. Make sure the result is what you wanted. Then you add the `INSERT` statement.